# Count number of occurrence of words in cell array of cell arrays and display the words in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, count, cell

I have a first loop that stores in b the recalled words (meaning the words that correspond to a 1 in SUBJ.RECALL).

```
b=[]; 
for s=1:length(SUBJ)
for r=1:length(SUBJ(s).RECALL)
   words=SUBJ(s).WORDS{r};
 if max(SUBJ(s).RECALL{r}==1)
   b{s}{r}=(words(find(SUBJ(s).RECALL{r}))); 
 end
end
end
```

b{s}{r} displays the content of the last subject. b refers to all subjects and  is a 1x7 cell storing six 1x3 cells and one 1x2 cell. I would like to count the occurrence of the words contained in b and,if possible, also have the words displayed corresponding to each occurrence.
I have tried several ways, but none is very efficient. 
They are based in comparing pairs of subjects using ismember. The words are organized in different blocks and the order is randomized across subjects, that explains the different indexing in subject 1 and 2.

```
list1match=[]; %SUBJ1 %SUBJ2 
        s1l1=b{1}{1};
         l1=ismember(s1l1,b{2}{2});
         if max(l1)==1
            list1match=(s1l1(l1))
         end
         list1match=list1match(:);
         list1match=(horzcat(list1match,list1match));%SUBJ1 %SUBJ2  
         list1nomatch=setxor(s1l1,b{2}{2})
```

Is there a way to do it globally? Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: Can you give us some simple example data and expected results?

Comment: why not using strsplit and strcmp for this?

Comment: Yes you are right @Suever. Here is a simple example:
SUBJ(1).WORDS{1}={‘Cheese’,’Cake’,’Panini’, ‘Avocado’,’Yoghurt’,’Milk’}
SUBJ(1).RECALL{1}=[1 0 0 1 1 1] % 1=remembered
SUBJ(2).WORDS{2}={’Panini’, Yoghurt’, ‘Cheese’,’Milk’, ’Cake’, ‘Avocado’,}
SUBJ(2).RECALL{2}=[0 0 1 1 0 0]
So every subject has 3 blocks of words, which order is randomized. That is why this list is the first for SUBJ(1), but the second for SUBJ(2). I would like to access the words contained in b, count their occurrence to know how many times was each word remembered and have the word displayed near the occurrence number.